# Python reading empty strings for Select Element/Website Dropdown menu when using dropDown.options[].text

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am writing a webscraping code to scrape PDFs from the USDA Web Soil Survey website. There is a block of code that contains a for loop. The purpose of the for loop is to loop through the "Depth to Restrictive Layer" options in the "Aggregation Method" drop down menu and select "Dominant Condition". There is another for loop which works properly and does a similar thing to loop through the "Restriction Kind" drop down menu and select each restriction available.

Here is the element code for each drop down:

The one that works properly:

```
<select name="Restriction_Kind" id="Restriction_Kind_00000" size="1" label="Restriction Kind">
  <option value="Fragipan" selected="selected">
    Fragipan
  </option>
  <option value="Lithic bedrock">
    Lithic bedrock
  </option>
  <option value="Paralithic bedrock">
    Paralithic bedrock
  </option>
</select>
```

The one that does not work:

```
<select name="Aggregation_Method" id="Aggregation_Method_00000" size="1" label="Aggregation Method">
  <option value="Dominant Condition">
    Dominant Condition
  </option>
  <option value="Dominant Component" selected="selected">
    Dominant Component
  </option>
  <option value="Weighted Average">
    Weighted Average
  </option>
  <option value="Minimum or Maximum">
    Minimum or Maximum
  </option>
</select>
```

Here is my code containing the two for loops:

```
dropDown1 = Select(driver.find_element(By.NAME,'Restriction_Kind'))
options = dropDown1.options
numOptions = range(len(options))

dropDown2 = Select(driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'Aggregation_Method'))

#Start counter
i = 0
optionsList = []

#Define a function to loop through the Aggregation methods to select "Dominant Condition"
def aggregationMethod():
    dropDown2 = Select(driver.find_element(By.NAME,'Aggregation_Method'))
    methods = dropDown2.options
    numMethods = range(len(methods))

    j = 0
    methodsList = []

    for m in numMethods:
        aggMethod = dropDown2.options[j].text
        methodsList.append(aggMethod)

        j = j + 1

    dropDown2.select_by_visible_text(methodsList[0])

#Loop through options to print the Individual Restrictive Layers PDfs
for n in numOptions:
    restriction = dropDown1.options[i].text
    optionsList.append(restriction)

    dropDown1.select_by_visible_text(optionsList[i])

    aggregationMethod()

   
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[7]/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/div/form/table/tbody[3]/tr[6]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/label').click()

    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ParameterForm50ViewRating_bottom"]').click()
    time.sleep(5)

    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="controlbarprintbibid_unfold"]'))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="controlbarprintbibid_submit_button"]'))).click()
    time.sleep(5)

    mainPage = driver.window_handles[0]
    pdfViewer = driver.window_handles[1]

    driver.switch_to.window(pdfViewer)

    url = driver.current_url
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    fileName = projectName + '_Depth_to_Restrictive_Layer_' + optionsList[i] + '.pdf'
    pdf = open(fileName,'wb')
    pdf.write(html.read())
    html.close()
    pdf.close()

    #Increment Counter
    i = i + 1

    driver.switch_to.window(mainPage)


# Exit for loop and print the success statement
print('07 Depth to INDIVIDUAL Restrictive Layers PDFs Created')
time.sleep(5)
```

When the code "runs properly"
the variable methodsList should become a list containing ['Dominant Condition', 'Dominant Component', 'Weighted Average', 'Minimum or Maximum']

I expected the code to be able to select "Dominant Condition" for the Aggregation Method drop down box from within my larger code file. Instead It only runs properly when I separate that section of code into a different "test.py" file.

This indicates to me that the code is written properly. So I need help figuring out why it wont run properly inside the bigger code file.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: In `aggregationMethod()`, what's the point of looping over all the options if you only care about the text of the first option?

Comment: Is the indentation of `driver.find_element(By.XPATH,...)` correct? If it should be inside the `for` loop, it needs to be indented.

Comment: Yes that indentation is there is the actual code. For some reason it showed up incorrectly when I pasted the code on this website to upload my question.

Comment: @Barmar I understand what you’re saying. I only tried a for loop because it wouldn’t work when I tried to do dropDown2.select_by_visible_text(‘Dominant Condition’) by itself/without a for loop.

Comment: As I mentioned the issue is getting the code to execute properly from within the larger code file. It only executes correctly when I separate this block of code into a test.py file.

Comment: If the code wasn't copied correctly, you should edit the question to fix it.

Comment: `methodsList` is a local variable in the `aggregationMethod()` function. So when the function completes, the variable will be gone. Move the variable initialization out of the function if you want it to persist.